# Remove an item in List if not exists in other list using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have two different types of Lists

```
class A

{

int number;

string name;

}

class B

{

int number;

}

List<A> a1;

List<B> b1;
```

And now both the lists were populated and now i want to remove items(number) in list a1 if that item(number) not exists in list b1.tried the below approach

```
a1.removeall(a=>b1.Exists(b1.number!=a1.number);
```

but the result is not as expected.Please help me...

Answer (score 5):

I think you want this:

```
a1.RemoveAll(a=> !b1.Any(b=> b.number == a.number));
```

Be aware though that this is O(n^2). A more performant approach would be using a `HashSet<int>` (this might not matter for small lists but be aware of this for larger ones):

```
 HashSet<int> bNums = new HashSet<int>(b1.Select(b => b.number));
 a1.RemoveAll(a => !bNums.Contains(a.number));
```